# back propagation through time derivation issue

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I read several posts about BPTT for RNN, but I am actually a bit confused about one step in the derivation.  Given

$$h_t=f(b+Wh_{t-1}+Ux_t)$$

when we compute $\frac{\partial h_t}{\partial W}$, does anyone know why is it simply

$$\frac{\partial h_t}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial h_{t}}{\partial h_{t-1}}\frac{\partial h_{t-1}}{\partial W}$$

not

$$\frac{\partial h_t}{\partial W}=\frac{\partial h_{t}}{\partial h_{t-1}}\frac{\partial h_{t-1}}{\partial W}+\frac{\partial h_t}{\partial f}h_{t-1}$$

?

What I mean is, since both $W$ and $h_{t-1}$ depends on $W$, why is the second term in the expression above missing?

Thank you!

Comment: @nbro Because W is W itself, $\frac{\partial W}{\partial W} = 1$.  I am not trying to do a total derivative, but only partial derivative wrt W.

Comment: can you provide a reference for the first version of $\frac{\partial h_t}{\partial W}$

Comment: @shimao Sure, one example is https://kharshit.github.io/blog/2019/02/22/backpropagation-through-time, where they denoted "h" as "s".

Comment: @username123 in that link, they correctly write $\frac{\partial h_t}{W} = \sum_{i<t} \frac{h_t}{h_i} \frac{\partial h_i}{W}$